# Unable to Parse a JSON Object iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

When I try to Parse a JSON object,

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: reportData, options: []) as? [String : Any]
```

I get an error saying that

> Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type
>   'with:([String:Any]), options:[Any]'

Here is my **reportData** in JSON format, obtained from Server

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "Report exists",
    "patientReport": {
        "caseId": "case040784",
        "Observations": "These are test observations",
        "userUid": "MY5FDbl0bgZStAY5Ky6OtYAzbDT2",
        "nextSteps": "Here are my next steps",
        "customerUid": "customerUid",
        "results": {
            "test1": "12",
            "test3": "15",
            "test3": "12"
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Seems your `jsonData` is already a Swift Dictionary of type `[String: Any]`. You have no need to _parse_ it. Just use it as a Swift Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function:

`jsonObject(with: Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = [])`

requires two parameters with type `Data` and `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions`.

Your `reportData` is `Dictionary` not a `Data`. So you can use it without parse to `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

> `Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type 'with:([String:Any]), options:[Any]'`

I think this may be the strangest thing I've seen today.

Reading this message literally says that `reportData` is of type `([String: Any])`—A tuple containing a single value `[String: Any]`.

After reading [*Creating Tuples For a Single Value*](https://andybargh.com/tuples-in-swift/#Creating_Tuples_For_a_Single_Value), I see there is no difference between `([String: Any])` and `[String: Any]`.

The other users have already answered it… You don't need to parse the already dictionary object, I just found the tuple thing intresting.